# Yarn command in docker-compose can't find && command

Tags: docker, vue.js, yarnpkg

I'm using docker on one of my vue projects. I want to run the command `yarn --silent` and `yarn serve` back to back in my dockerfile, but it doesn't see `yarn --silent` as command. Any way to fix this?

The code looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    build: 
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: yarn --silent && yarn serve
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: app
    volumes:
       - ./app:/usr/src/app
       - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

**EDIT**

When I change the command to `yarn install --silent && yarn serve` I get the following error:
`error 'install' has been replaced with 'add' to add new dependencies.  Run "yarn add && yarn serve" instead.` but this will not install all dependencies ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shared your `Dockerfile` but I assume **you have `yarn` installed** in the docker container, have you?

If so, try with replacing your command with the following:

```
command: bash -c "yarn --silent && yarn serve"
```

*Note: I assume there is `bash` in your container, if not replace it with with the supported one - `sh`, etc.*

Comment: Thanks this worked! Only needed to change bash to sh :)